# User input history on graph

Tags: java, android, graph

Created a graph (xml and java file) and trying to set points on graph with history of user values inputed for a specific graph.

I'm doing that with SharedPreferences because SQLite is too complex for me (only one month of coding experience) and I run into an error.

I did what user of StackOverflow told me but it can't resolve constructor DataPoint.. if I parse it to double it still does not work because "add" is in red too and Android Studio recommends to add qualifier to a method.. But that doesn't work too..

Anyway, here's the code:

```
public class StatistikaGrafoviMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistika_grafovi_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add("150");
        set.add("200");
        settings.edit().putStringSet("tezinaMetricSave", set);

        Set<String> prefSet = settings.getStringSet("tezinaMetricSave", null);
        String[] vals = prefSet.toArray(new String[prefSet.size()]);



        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();

        for (int i=0;i<vals.length;i++){
            series.add(new DataPoint(vals[i], i));
        }
        graph.addSeries(series);


    }

}
```

Can anyone help me?